# YFinance - tickerData.info not working for some stocks

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf

#define the ticker symbol
tickerSymbol = "AFT.NZ"

#get data on this ticker
tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)
print(tickerData.info)
```

This doesn't seem to work. `IndexError: list index out of range`

Replace "AFT.NZ" with "MSFT" or "FPH.NZ" and it works fine. Going to the Yahoo website, can't see why it wouldn't have data on it.

What's more confusing, is that replacing `print(tickerData.info)` with `tickerDf = tickerData.history(period='max')` does print some of the data.

I need the info because I want the full name of the company along with the currency the shares are traded in. Which is why just having the price data isn't the solution.

The AFT.NZ is just an example, most others on the NZX50 seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a merge request from ***williamsiuhang*** to fix this that's currently 9 days old.
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/pull/371/commits/7e137357296a1df177399d26543e889848efc021

I just made the change manually myself, go into base.py (in ***your_py_dir\Lib\site-packages\yfinance***) and change line 286:

old line:

```
self._institutional_holders = holders[1]
```

new line:

```
self._institutional_holders = holders[1] if len(holders) > 1 else []
```

Comment: Still not fixed 6 months later, but your solution is easy and still works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and see there's a lot of posts on github with the same error.

I've fixed the error with a try & except in the base.py file for yfinance

Line 282

```
    # holders
    try:
        url = "{}/{}/holders".format(self._scrape_url, self.ticker)
        holders = _pd.read_html(url)
        self._major_holders = holders[0]
        self._institutional_holders = holders[1]

        if 'Date Reported' in self._institutional_holders:
            self._institutional_holders['Date Reported'] = _pd.to_datetime(
                self._institutional_holders['Date Reported'])
        if '% Out' in self._institutional_holders:
            self._institutional_holders['% Out'] = self._institutional_holders[
            '   % Out'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)/100
    except:
        print("institutional_holders error")
```

Not a great solution, but makes it run for me. I'm not a great programmer, so I hope the problem get fixed in a more delicate way by the developer(s).