# yahoo_fin incomplete dataframe retrieval

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve the cashflow data for a company but it seems to me there is some data missing. There is no Free Cash flow and some other rows.

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
tickers = 'AAPL'
cf = si.get_cash_flow(tickers, yearly = True)
```

What I am getting is this cute dataframe:

[image]

How ever If I look at the yahoo finance website I see there is a row with the free cash flow data

[image]

I have tried to reinstall the module and also used yfinance to see if that made a difference but it gave more or less the same result.

Does anybody know what the cause is and if it is possible to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do the yfinance docs have to say about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting financial data from yahoo finance with yfinance python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171316/getting-financial-data-from-yahoo-finance-with-yfinance-python)

Comment: It does not unfortunately the description is as follows: get_cash_flow(ticker, yearly = True)
Scrapes the cash flow statement for the input ticker from Yahoo Finance (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/cash-flow?p=NFLX.  Which returns the cash flow page of Yahoo Finance with the missing free cash flow